# Select non-redundant data from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, redundancy

I have a table like that has two attributes `a` and `b`. Now, there's a lot of data going through that stuff and I'd like to select all records where one value for `a` has more than 1 different value of `b`.

For example, from the following example table

```
   a    b
---------
   1    1
   1    1
   2    1
   2    2
   3    1
   4    1
   4    5
   4    1
```

I'd like to select

```
   a   b
--------
   2   1
   2   2
   4   1
   4   5
```

Or if not otherwise possible just `2` and `4` (as two result rows), so I can get more specific data in a second query.

I've tried working with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` and also some constructs with subqueries, but nothing came close to the result I want. I really don't want to fetch all the data and crunch through manually.

It's probably something really simple, but I just cant get to it, so how would one solve this?

Comment: @JW. because they're the only present combination for `a=1` and `a=3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single table access (that returns all values of `b` for a specific value of `a` on the same line), try:

```
select a, group_concat(distinct b)
from yourtable
group by a
having count(distinct b) > 1
```

To return separate rows for each combination of a and b, try:

```
select distinct yt1.a, yt1.b
from yourtable yt1
join yourtable yt2 on yt1.a = yt2.a and yt1.b <> yt2.b
```

`Exists` variant:

```
select distinct a, b
from yourtable yt1
where exists
(select 1
 from yourtable yt2
 where yt1.a = yt2.a and yt1.b <> yt2.b)
```

Comment: Wow thanks! Used your second variant with an appended `GROUP BY b` because I'm having a few more columns in my production environment. ;)